# JVisualVM indicates -Xmx is being ignored when passed inline

Tags: java, memory, jvisualvm

Read through a number of similar issues and some were completely different or didn't provide an explanation.

Here is how the application is executed. A size of 1234M is used to ensure no default value is being picked up. Also verified no Java related Environment Variables are set.

```
> java -Xms512M -Xmx1234M -jar myApp.jar
```

When the application loads, JVisualVM shows the following and based on the JVM Arguments the -Xmx is visble.

[image: -Xmx1234M is visible here]

Under the Monitor tab, the graphical view is inspected and this shows a max heap size of 8G.

[image: 8Gigs of heap]

If multiple applications are running, this could be problematic. 
As a test, the _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2222m environment variable is set. The value 2222 is used to help verify no default value gets picked up.

Once again JVisualVM shows the proper size passed in :

[image: 2nd Test]

Under the Monitor tab, the graphical view is inspected and this shows the value from the environment variable.

[image: Correct value here.]

Why does java not pickup the values passed in via the command line?